# Bootstrap modal not showing in bootstrap carousel except active carousel item

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap carousel with few slides. Each slide contain few image button to launch a modal. However, I found that only active carousel item can launch the modal.

When Click the image in first slide, the function runs normally.

I found that when I click the image button in other slide, the source code tell me the modal was open. However, only grey screen showing up.

```
<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;">

<div>class="modal-backdrop fade show" </div>
```

//Carousel

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>

<!-- The slideshow -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="2"><img src="images\fabio.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="3"><img src="images\EDDY.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="4"><img src="images\West.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="5"><img src="images\ALEX.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="6"><img src="images\Gary.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="7"><img src="images\i8.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
/div>


<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="8"><img src="images\Owen.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="9"><img src="images\Keble.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>


</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a  id="move1" class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data- 
slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark"></span>
</a>
<a  id="move2" class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data- 
slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark"></span>
</a>

</div>
```

//Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
$('.carousel').carousel('pause');
})


$('a.playerbutton').click(function(event) {
var status = $(this).attr('id');
var url = "modal.php?id=" + status;
$('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
    $('#modal' + status).modal({show:true});
    });
    }); 
    });
```

\modal.php

```
<!--  player Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal<?php echo $id; ?>" aria- 
hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Player Info</h5>
  </div>
 <div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
 <div class="progress-bar bg-secondary" role="progressbar" style="width: 
 80%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
 </div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid border border-dark  news ">
<div class="card-header bg-dark text-white text-center ">Player 
Info</div>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-5 "><img src= "<?php echo $path; ?>" 
  class="playerimg"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
  <p class="comp1"> ID: <?php echo $name; ?></p>
  <p class="comp1"> Jersey No:<?php echo $number; ?></p>
  <p class="comp1"> Position :<?php echo $pos; ?></p>
  <p class="comp1"> Nationalities:<?php echo $nation; ?></p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br>
<div class="container-fluid border border-dark  news ">
<div class="card-header bg-dark text-white text-center ">Stats</div>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <table class="pstat">
      <tr class="bg-dark text-white text-center">
<th>Competition</th>
<th>Apps</th> 
<th>Goal</th>
<th>Assist</th>
<th>Yellow Card</th>
<th>Red Card</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="compinpstat">Taiwan Fifa Premier League Season 12</td>
<td>0</td> 
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
 </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--  player Modal -->
```

Expected Output ( Active Slide Output):
[First Slide output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pdby.png)

Now:

[Fail to show modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoeHL.png)

I don't know what happening.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for solving my issue.

That's the part I can click and launch the modal properly. I tried to change the content in not active carousel row to active carousel row, and It works properly. So, I guess It's maybe related to active carousel class.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="2"><img src="images\fabio.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="3"><img src="images\EDDY.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="4"><img src="images\West.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="5"><img src="images\ALEX.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you check if '#modal' + status is load truth (for any request not open modal)? (open console, and select network and look to ajax request when click on button).

Comment: Also, theirs something wrong, ```$('.modal-container')``` which its mean all modal container, you can say ```$(this).find('.modal-container')..``` (I think this will resolve issue)

Comment: Hello Anees, thanks for answering my question, Because I have other page that cotain all the image button and it works perfect without carousel. So, I think the jquery can load the modal data that I want.

Comment: Welcome shelvey33, its no problem, are you try my solution in second comment?

Comment: I have tried to change it to $(this).find('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
$('#modal' + status).modal({show:true}); });

But I can't launch any modal with this code. Even the modal work properly in previous jquery function.

Comment: Show yourself which slide you're clicking on, maybe it's only working for the first one because it only takes the first one. Showing which you are clicking, maybe this is the problem, so just change the click with Jquery

Comment: Updated in the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this: `$(document).on('click', 'a.playerbutton', function(){ var status = $(this).attr('id'); console.log(status);  }); ` this will show whether the clicked slide is correctly referenced

Comment: I can launch each of the four modal in first slide, that is <div class="carousel-item active">  <div class="row"> content </div>. However, when I click the control button to next slide, modals in that slide will not shown and sometimes that modal show up when the carousel turn back to original active carousel slide. I am so confused.

Comment: I tried the above code that can show the id I am clicking in the console. I think the main issue is the carousel class